# AjaxBased Framework in .NET?

Tags: .net, ajax, javascript, zk

I'm developing a .NET based web project for public transport system in Norway. Prior to this, i've worked in Java Platform. I worked in AjaxBased framework like Zk and GWT in Java. I was wondering if there is any similar frameworks in .NET? I would be glad enough to find such framework and to be able to use my previous framework knowledge(in Java) into .NET.Thanx in advance.

-neo

Comment: For ASP.NET MVC I think they call something close to Zk, Unobtrusive Javascript. Not really a JSless framework but partway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things come to mind.  If you are looking for framework that will allow to generated Javascript from C# code then [ScriptSharp](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) is a good choice.

There are several good resources for developing Ajax applications with jQuery, ASP.Net / MVC.  The best resource I have learned from is Dave Ward's blog [Encosia](http://www.encosia.com/) where he focuses on issues such as using jQuery to post [directly to a .Net Web Service or PageMethod](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).  On the home page of his blog are the posts that can get you started.  Dave writes clearly and concisely while providing straight forward samples.  I would start there to learn the mechanics as opposed to starting with a framework.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cent.
I've tried different javascript/ajax frameworks ([YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/)) and many other small ones but ended up using jQuery. It is the easier one to implement and use. There are tons of plugins you can use and loads of blogger who are trying to "spread the verb".
The jQuery team have put together an amazing framework to [manage interface elements](http://jqueryui.com/).
You have a really amazing [jquery grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) to use for free.

Plus (I don't really know if it is a plus ;-) ) MS is supporting it ...
There are many tutorials and video-tutorials:

http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/video/index.htm  (video)
http://www.learningjquery.com/
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/
https://github.com/rmurphey/jqfundamentals  (free book and samples)

If you prefer you can even buy these [video tutorials](http://tekpub.com/productions/jquery)

Comment: thanx for the new resources for jQuery...i'm enjoying them...!